# How to get processed object and set it a new value to it in Java via Reflection API?

Tags: oop, reflection, java

I was searching and learning Java Reflection API more about it. But I could not find some part of my problem's solution in it. The problem is, I want to change just one value of my object which was assigned by a user. Here is my code for further observation;

```
    public class Car{
          private String model_name;
          private int horsepower;
          public Tire t;

          public void setModelName(String s){
              model_name = s;
          }

          public void setHorsePower(int i){
              horsepower = i;
          }

          public String getModelName(){
              return model_name;
          }

          public int getHorsePower(){
              return horsepower;
          }
    }

    // Tire.java

    public class Tire{
          private String name;

          public void setName(String s){
              name = s;
          }

          public String getName(){
              return name;
          }
    }

    // Main class

    public class Main{
       public static void main(String []args){
           Car a = new Car();
           a.setModelName("Mustang 67");
           a.setHorsePower(700);
           a.t = new Tire("DummyBrand");
           Class c = a.getClass();
           Field []f = c.getDeclaredFields();
           for(int i = 0; i < f.length; i++){
               if(f[i].getType().getSimpleName().toString().matches("Tire"){
                   // How to change a object's t field's name variable? 
               }
           }
           System.out.printline(a.getModelName)   
       }
    }
```

I would be gladful if you guys and ladies can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I added my detailed question in code. How to change a object's a field's name variable?

Comment: have you read this? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html

Comment: variable name? That's impossible. It's part of the class metadata.

Comment: Isn't there a way to change with using set() method? Can I do assign field object to Object typed object and change its one value inside it and set it with set() method? I am sorry for the inadequate explanation by the way :/

Comment: Why do you even want to use reflection. Why can't you just use the setter?

Comment: I am building a 2D game framework. The user might create some object in their Canvas. And that object might construct some unwanted memory allocation. I just want to interrupt the user's object to make them more efficient and more robust.

Comment: Above code is not genuine code. It is just code that I can express my problem to you guys.

Comment: Reflection comes with a lot of overhead. it is leagues slower than just using a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Method setName = Tire.class.getDeclaredMethod("setName", String.class);
setName.invoke(a.t, "new value");
```

Comment: For experimental purposes this is fine. But from a programming perspective these things must be avoided :)

Comment: Could you give me another example of using Field? I tried to use set() method in following code line.  field.set(c.t, s); // c is Car object. But it gave me IllegalArgumentException. "Can not set java.lang.String field java.lang.reflect.Field.name to reflect.Tire"

Comment: By the way, appreciate it for the answer. That was the answer I was looking for. Thanks again. Still, I am curious about my answer above :)

Comment: @YektaSarıoğlu `Field nameField = Tire.class.getDeclaredField("name");  nameField.setAccessible(true);  nameField.set(a, "new value");`

Comment: Please mark it as the right answer if that is what you were looking for. For your other question. It would not be correct as the name is a private variable and you would not be able to set it without invoking the setter method.

Comment: Actually, it solved my problem. But i am trying to understand how can I achieve that with using Field? Because it did work when you want to achieve one field of the object. When i tried to apply the idea to my given code example above gave me error which was hard to identify the problem.